# How can I create simple installer, that install single image file?

Tags: flash, installation, exe, cs3

I am working with old "cs3 flash" project, and to save image in file system, i need to create .exe installer that install one image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of setup authoring tools which can create installation packages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Pick one, try to build the installer you want and ask more specific questions if you encounter any problems.